# Need a function to do this in Perl

Tags: perl

Sample Input:

```
ATAT

GATATATGCATATACTT
```

Sample Output:

```
1 3 9
```

I get the regex part but I don't understand how we can use a position instance.

Answer (score 3):

The built-in array `@-` holds the positions where the last successful regex and its captures appear in the target string. So `$-[0]` says where the entire pattern matched, while `$-[1]` etc. hold the positions for captures `$1` etc.

In combination with this, you need to use a *forward look-ahead* instead of a simple regex, otherwise the regex engine will start looking for subsequent matches only *after the end* of the previous match it found, and so won't find overlapping occurrences.

This code will do as you ask.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $seq = 'GATATATGCATATACTT';

my @offsets;
push @offsets, $-[0] while $seq =~ /(?=ATAT)/g;
print "@offsets\n";
```

**output**

```
1 3 9
```

Answer (score 1):

No need for a regex, `index` can do all the work:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $substring = 'ATAT';
my $string    = 'GATATATGCATATACTT';

my @positions;
my $pos = -1;
while (-1 != ($pos = index $string, $substring, $pos + 1)) {
    push @positions, $pos;
}
print "@positions\n";
```